# Unable to import dataset Ionosphere in Rstudio

Tags: r, import, dataset

I'm loading the dataset `Ionosphere` in Rstudio:

> [image]

Could you please help me resolve the error `object 'Ionosphere' not found`?

It's weird because the code runs well in [Rdocumentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mlbench/versions/2.1-1/topics/Ionosphere)

> [image: 1]

Comment: You need to load the package that contains the dataset first, i.e. `library(mlbench)`.

Comment: All good - someone else has since posted step by step.  Feel free to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you need to download a package called "mlbench" inside that package you will find that data .

Try to do the following:

```
install.packages("mlbench") #to install the package (use if not already installed)
library(mlbench) #to import the library 
data(Ionosphere) #to import the data
```